# Load file from Google Drive into Bigquery

Tags: google-api, google-bigquery, google-drive-api

I have an API which takes a loaded file on my website and uploads it with mimeType text/csv to Google Drive via the API.

This creates and works wonders, however, I now need to load that file into Google Bigquery as a permanent table.

I have two ways:

1. Preferred: Take the uploaded file and ammend the mimeType to Google Sheets - i thought drive would be clever enough to do this with a csv but apparently not - maybe there is a way.
2. Load the file from text/csv straight into Bigquery - i am receiving invalid URI's

I have my PHP CURL command below:

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/xxxxxxx/datasets/xxxxx/tables",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{\n  \"externalDataConfiguration\": {\n    \"sourceUris\": [\n      \"https://drive.google.com/file/d/{$id}/\"\n    ],\n    \"sourceFormat\": \"CSV\",\n    \"autodetect\": true\n  },\n  \"tableReference\": {\n    \"tableId\": \"{$user}\"\n  }\n}",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Accept: */*",
    "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate",
    "Authorization: Bearer",
    "Cache-Control: no-cache",
    "Connection: keep-alive",
    //"Content-Length: 319",
    "Content-Type: application/json",
    "Host: bigquery.googleapis.com",
    "User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.17.1",
    "cache-control: no-cache"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

Getting back the following - using method two - however, first prize would be to getting step 1 working, changing the file type to Google Sheets - I already have an update function setting the Title so if i need to add on to that I can

```
"Invalid source URI: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Zt6OMQqE3rj1PJe4HlokQ4LPNfOPBHfB/
```

Answer (score 1):

From [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data):

> Loading data into BigQuery from Google Drive is not currently supported, but you can query data in Google Drive by using an external table.

Follow [Querying Google Drive data](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-drive) and once you can query it, you may persist it to BigQuery using query (or your don't have to if external table works for you already):

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_dataset.persisted_table_name
AS SELECT * FROM my_external_table_pointing_to_google_drive;
```

Comment: Hi Yun, I am busy testing this out first in Bigquery itself before I use the bigquery.jobs - would the my_external_table_pointing_to_google_drive; be the equivalent of my drive URI i.e.: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1RUKQBqQcYxclEUCaN0mWkarVqYWER (I have removed some characters)  My problem is even when I load it from Create Table selecting Drive put in the correct format it can't find the table, yet I am using the exact same google account and everything, once it creates an empty table I click on external resource and it opens fine?

Comment: Have you tried https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-drive?

Comment: Yip,I have gone through it, as a test I just went through the Console, went Create table, selected drive used the URI: https://drive.google.com/open?id=file_id. With the correct ID and it just says file not found

Comment: I personally never used g drive to do upload and most commonly, people uses Google Cloud Storage. If you cannot figure out the gdrive story, GCS is a good alternative.

Comment: Thanks Yun, only reason I wanted to use drive was because of the apparent easy convert, it is supposed auto convert text/csv to google sheets on upload, from there I am rest assured the data uploaded will auto detect the schema, whereas with GCS there is the question of what delimeter was used on upload. I have found the problem with drive, it is permission driven, same account apparently means nothing... I don't think the drive API is the greatest, considering it is free almost feels lii Google is pushing you to the paid service, which I don't mind but still frustrring, thanks for the help

Comment: Great! It will be helpful to others if you can share the issue that you had and how you managed to resolve it.